# Is there a way to retrieve all attributes of an Object? (Using Fuel-sdk)

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, documentation

I am using the python fuel-sdk,

Say I want to fetch data-extensions, but instead of specifying which specific attributes I want, can I tell the fuel-sdk just give me all the attributes of the data-extension?

i.e instead of doing:

```
de = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension()
de.auth_stub = stubObj
de.props = ["attribute_1", "attribute_2"]
getResponse = de.get()
```

Can I do something like:

```
de = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension()
de.auth_stub = stubObj
de.options = {"fetchAllAttributes: "true"}
getResponse = de.get()
```

I am particularly interested in this, because it appears the documentation I am looking at is outdated, and I cannot find a more up-to-date version,
(i am looking at https://help.exacttarget.com/de-AT/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/ ).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way (that I know of) to retrieve all of the property names.  Even if you got all the names, not all of them are retreiveable.  In the SFMC SDK we built, we created a set of metadata for each object that specifies the retrievable properties.

The two spots for API documentation are:

[Web Service Guide (help.exacttarget.com)](https://help.exacttarget.com/de-AT/technical_library/web_service_guide/)

[APIs & SDKs (code.exacttarget.com)](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/)